# C++ Exceptions in Console App?

Tags: c++, exception, console

May be a dumb question, but I would like to use C++ exceptions in a console app (created with the new Win32 Console Application project wizard).  I tried many variations on the theme shown below with no joy:

```
try {
  // do something that may throw an exception
}
catch( exception e ) {
  printf( "Exception: %s\n", e.what );
}
```

The compiler complains that identifier 'exception' not found.
I tried various things in place of 'exception' (e.g., 'IOException', 'bad_alloc') with no luck.

I tried different exception-related options in the project configuration, also with no luck.
I **was** able to make it compile using

```
catch(...) {
```

but that gives me no info about the exception.

Questions:
Are exceptions even **allowed** in non-.NET apps?
Am I missing some include file?
Some other (dumb) thing I did or didn't do?

Comment: _"The compiler complains that identifier 'exception' not found."_ Ehhrm. Did you `#include <exception>` and have a `using namespace std;` in your code? Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your error please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are exceptions even allowed in non-.NET apps?

Yes, they are.

> Am I missing some include file?

It looks like you're missing the necessary `#include <exception>` and/or the namespace scoping with `std::`.

> Some other (dumb) thing I did or didn't do?

The better way to catch exceptions is by const reference BTW:

```
#include <exception>

int main() {
    try {
      // do something that may throw an exception
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e ) {
        printf( "Exception: %s\n", e.what );
    }
}
```

Comment: The reference part of your const reference is missing ;-)

Comment: @SimonKraemer THX, fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I added "#include <exception>" and the error went away.

Comment: @DontPanic Just to get you noted: From your nick most of your questions may be answered with `42` ;)